# Python file not executing correctly through systemd

Tags: systemd, python, startup

I have a python file to update an A-Record on my CPanel web host. It imports a module named `cpanelapi` which is located in the same directory as the `ddns.py` file.

When I execute `ddns.py` from the command line `/usr/bin/python ddns.py` it runs correctly with no errors. However when run from systemd or crontab it fails with `ImportError: No module named cpanelapi`.

This is the systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Update A-Record
AssertPathExists=/home/ethan/cpanel-ddns-client
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ethan
WorkingDirectory=/home/ethan/cpanel-ddns-client
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/ethan/cpanel-ddns-client/ddns.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script is located at `cpanel-ddns-client/ddns.py` and the module is located at `cpanel-ddns-client/cpanelapi`.

I have tried adding the `cpanel-ddns-client` folder to `sys.path` which did not work.

Comment: Does `env - /usr/bin/python ddns.py` work in the shell?

Comment: @HaukeLaging No, it crashes with an import error

Comment: Then the reason for your problem is one or more environment variables which are set in your shell but not by cron or systemd. You have to identify those, then you can configure them for the daemons.